# C# mono console app reading MJPEG stream hanging

Tags: c#, mono, aforge, mjpeg, strace

I have a console application written in C# .Net 4.5 and running on Mono 3.2.8 on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).

The console app is started as a service with upstart and I am logging output using log4net v2.0.5 and a console appender.

Upstart redirects all the output in /var/log/upstart/{appname}.log

Randomly, after few hours up to a couple of days, the application hangs and I see nothing in the logs.

What I know:

- Disk is not full
- Memory is not full and there is no swap
- Command ps shows the process still running
- The application is not sending anymore data to external server. When working properly the external server receives data every few seconds.
- Log file is not populated anymore

I used the command strace to see the last syscall and this is what I get:

> $ strace -p 5602
>
> Process 5602 attached
>
> poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
>
> --- SIGPWR {si_signo=SIGPWR, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=5602, si_uid=1001} ---
>
> rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [XCPU], NULL, 8) = 0
>
> futex(0x26b18c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
>
> rt_sigsuspend(~[XCPU RTMIN RT_1])       = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
>
> --- SIGXCPU {si_signo=SIGXCPU, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=5602, si_uid=1001} ---
>
> rt_sigreturn()                          = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
>
> rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [XCPU], NULL, 8) = 0
>
> futex(0x26b18c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
>
> rt_sigreturn()                          = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)

The 2 file descriptors 6 and 8 are pipes:

> $ file /proc/5602/fd/6
>
> /proc/5602/fd/6: broken symbolic link to pipe:[6562495]'
>
> $ file /proc/5602/fd/8
>
> /proc/5602/fd/8: broken symbolic link to pipe:[6562496]'

I do not understand the root cause of the issue and I do not know what to try to fix it.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by [@sushihangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover) I ran the app in a terminal with --debug option. Eventually the app hanged again. No exception, no error.

The code is acquiring frames from MJPEG streams and doing some work on a background worker to detect object in the frame.

The work only happens when the background worker is not busy. The last log trace I get is:

> [Background worker] nothing to do

I suspect the app is hanging while trying to get the next frame from the camera. I am using AForge.NET to read the MJPEG stream. AForge raise an events every time a new frame arrives.

Here is some code:

```
    private static void Camera_NewFrame(object sender, NewImageEventArgs e)
    {
        var bmp = (Bitmap)e.Frame;
        log.DebugFormat("got image " + DateTime.Now.Ticks + " {0} x {1}", bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

        if (!bWorker.IsBusy)
        {
            // Run the background operation to check image and update cloud
            log.Debug("Starting background work");
            bWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else { } // skip frame 
    }

    private static void BWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        log.Debug("[Background worker] enter");
        if (registeredCar)
        {
            log.Debug("[Background worker] opening the gate");
            OpenGate();
        }
        else
        {
            log.Debug("[Background worker] nothing to do");
        }
    }
```

And the backtrace given by gdb attached to the hanging process:

> (gdb) bt
>
> 0  0xb6e19fc0 in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
>
> 1  0xb4b264be in Mono_Unix_UnixSignal_WaitAny () from /usr/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.so
>
> 2  0xb4b6f740 in ?? ()

Comment: It could just be a network error, hard to say without some code. Do you have reconnecting logic? is your code dependant on certain ports?

Comment: Without code or a stack trace..... You should look at running for exe with `--debug` and after it *hangs* attaching either the `sdb` or `gdb` to the Mono process....

Comment: @prof1990 Code is quite large and there is just some post of data to a rest web service. No permanent connection. There is no permanent connection. I am not fully understanding the strace output. To me it looks like the app is polling something but not sure what.

Comment: @SushiHangover I will try to reproduce the problem in a terminal and do as you suggest. Thank you.